# How to create dataframe using dictionary by matching the index in the max_min variable that i created

Tags: python, dataframe

How can I use the dictionary to convert to dataframe that this dictionary values is coming from the variable max_min of index that I hope that could match the index of max_min and create the dataframe I need.

The example code below is coming from this website:

https://medium.com/automation-generation/algorithmically-detecting-and-trading-technical-chart-patterns-with-python-c577b3a396ed

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXCtM.png)

```
def max_min(smoothing=5, window_range=10,parse_dates=[0]):
smooth_prices = df['Price'].rolling(window=smoothing).mean().dropna()
local_max = argrelextrema(smooth_prices.values, np.greater)[0]
local_min = argrelextrema(smooth_prices.values, np.less)[0]
price_local_max_dt = []
for i in local_max:
    if (i>window_range) and (i<len(df)-window_range):
        price_local_max_dt.append(df.iloc[i-window_range:i+window_range]['Price'].idxmax())
price_local_min_dt = []
for i in local_min:
    if (i>window_range) and (i<len(df)-window_range):
        price_local_min_dt.append(df.iloc[i-window_range:i+window_range]['Price'].idxmin())  
maxima = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[price_local_max_dt])
minima = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[price_local_min_dt])
max_min = pd.concat([maxima, minima]).sort_index()
return max_min
```

max_min = max_min()

def find_patterns1(max_min):
    patterns1 = defaultdict(list)

```
# Window range is 5 units
for i in range(5, len(max_min)):  
    window = max_min.iloc[i-5:i]

    a = window.iloc[0]
    b = window.iloc[1]
    c = window.iloc[2]
    d = window.iloc[3]
    e = window.iloc[4]           
    # IHS
    if c.Price<d.Price and a.Price<c.Price and a.Price<b.Price and a.Price<e.Price and b.Price<e.Price and abs(d.Price-e.Price)<=np.mean([d.Price,e.Price])*0.03:
           patterns1['IHS'].append((window.index[0], window.index[-1]))
return patterns1
patterns1 = find_patterns1(max_min)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html). Depends on how you'd want to structure your DataFrame, you can use the `orient` parameter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(patterns, orient = 'index')
```

Will give you: 1st column for all the keys in your dictionary and 2nd column for your values.

There's a `columns` parameter too where you can give names to your expected columns by placing them in a list.

Hope this helps :)). Welcome to the community.

Comment: Thank for help!! Really appreciate it very much!! And try my best to learn python from this community^^

Comment: Sure man, np. Don't forget to upvote the posts of everyone that helped you and accept answers. Have a good one :D

Answer (score 0):

`patterns` variable is an instance of the class `collections.defaultdict` which is a subclass of `dict`
You can convert a dict to a pandas DataFrame using `DataFrame.from_dict()` function

Example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(patterns)
```

Note: Welcome to stackoverflow but try to fix your grammar as possible ;)

Comment: Thank you!! Appreciate it very much..^^